# Looking for decoding algorithm for datetime in MYSQL. See examples, reward for solution

Tags: mysql, algorithm

Have tried some of the online references as wells as unix time form at etc.  but none of these seem to work. See the examples below.

running  Mysql 5.5.5 in ubuntu.  innodb engine.
nothing is custom.  This is using a built in datetime function.

Here are some examples with the 6 byte hex string and the decoded message below.   We are looking for the decoding algorithm.  i.e.how to turn the 6 byte hex string into the correct date/time. The algorithm must work correctly on the examples below. The right most byte seems to indicate  difference in seconds correctly for small small differences in time between records. i.e. we show an example with 14 sec difference.

full records,nicely highlighted and formated word doc here.
https://www.dropbox.com/s/zsqy9o2rw1h0e09/mysql%20datetime%20examples%20.docx?dl=0
link to formatted word document with the examples.

contact frank%simrex.com re. reward.
replace % with @

```
hex strings and decoded date/time pairs are below.
pulled from healthy file running mysql

12 51 72 78 B9 46  ...   2014-10-22 16:53:18
12 51 72 78 B9 54  ...   2014-10-22 16:53:32
12 51 72 78 BA 13  ...   2014-10-22 16:55:23
12 51 72 78 CC 27  ...   2014-10-22 17:01:51
```

Comment: Reward for answer. Contact frank%simrex.com   replacing % with @

Comment: Whats the reward?  Have you looked up storage format of MySQL data types?

Comment: Are you aware that innodb is open source?

Answer (score 0):

here you go.

```
select str_to_date(conv(replace('12 51 72 78 CC 27',' ', ''), 16, 10), '%Y%m%d%H%i%s')
```